# Positioning messages from jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, positioning

i'm creating a form in a plugin for wordpress visible in frontend.
Using a JQuery validation method, i have problems positioning each error exactly under each fields.

So this is my script:

```
function validate_init() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#form_register').validate({
            rules: {
                ragsoc: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },

                piva: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                },

                gruppo: {
                    required: true,
                },
            },

            messages: {
                ragsoc: "Inserire la ragione sociale.",
                piva: "Solo numeri accettati.",
                gruppo: "inserire un valore.",
            },
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
    <?php }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'validate_init', 999);
```

and this is my form:

```
<?php echo '<form id="form_register" method="post" action="'.$pluginfolder.'/submit.php">'; ?>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><label for="ragsoc">Ragione sociale *</label>
      <input type="text" name="ragsoc" id="long" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="piva">Partita Iva *</label>
      <input type="text" name="piva" id="tris" /></td>
      <td><label for="codfisc">Codice Fiscale</label>
      <input type="text" name="codfisc" id="tris" /></td>
      <td><label for="gruppo">Gruppo</label>
      <input type="text" name="gruppo" id="tris" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="codice">Codice</label>
            <input type="text" name="codice" id="tris" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="insegna">Insegna *</label>
            <select id="tris" name="insegna">
                <option value=""><em>Scegli...</em></option>
                <option value="option_1">option_1</option>
                <option value="option_2">option_2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="rapporto">Rapporto *</label>
            <select id="tris" name="rapporto">
                <option value=""><em>Scegli...</em></option>
                <option value="option_1">option_1</option>
                <option value="option_2">option_2</option>
                <option value="option_3">option_3</option>                
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Invia" />
      <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Cancella" />
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Finally this is my css:

```
div.error{
color: #f33;
padding: 0;
margin: 2px 0 0 0;
font-size: 0.7em;
padding-left: 18px;
background-image: url('error.png');
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

All it's working fine but the position of the error message is wrong for the three column fields where the errors overlap as in the next image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzshN.jpg]

How can i obtain this effect (modified with photoshop):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3MiU.jpg]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your error placement code.  The majority of your issue was being caused by invalid HTML and missing rules.  (*I would not use a `table` for a `form` layout... there are better, more modern ways to do such layouts.*)

---

**Root causes:**

**1)**  You've repeated `id="tris"` on multiple elements which is invalid HTML and breaks the code.  Elements with duplicate `id`'s are ignored.  Use `class` instead.

**2)**  You've failed to define any rules for those four additional fields.  So of course, no errors will display anywhere.

---

**Good idea to fix:**

**3)**  Remove all of your trailing commas.  Although this only breaks the code in older versions of Internet Explorer, leaving trailing commas is a sloppy coding practice.

**4)**  You were missing the last `</td>` tag in the last `<tr></tr>` of your `table`.

**5)**  You do not need to specify a custom `errorPlacement` callback function if `error.insertAfter(element)` is the only code within.  Since this is just the default code of the plugin, it's ok to remove `errorPlacement` from your plugin options.

---

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/9bRXd/**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#form_register').validate({
        rules: {
            ragsoc: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            piva: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            codfisc: {
                required: true
            },
            gruppo: {
                required: true
            },
            insegna: {
                required: true
            },
            rapporto: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        messages: {
            ragsoc: "Inserire la ragione sociale.",
            piva: "Solo numeri accettati.",
            gruppo: "inserire un valore."
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: damn... the problem was the repeated id of input instead of using class. Now it's working fine. I just replaced id with class and the problem is solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to figure out if you post an example on jsFiddle but just looking at the code I would suggest this.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
                {
                  error.insertAfter(element);

                  // Use jQuery UI's position function to get placement correct
                  error.position ( {
                                     my: 'left top',
                                     at: 'left bottom',
                                     of: element
                                   } );
                }
```

This assumes you have jQuery UI as well as jQuery Validation plugin.  You may have to play around with the CSS of error to get it to look exactly how you want.

Here is the api for position: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: Even if the OP wanted to go through the bother of using an entire library just to position his errors, jQuery UI does not even come close to solving his problem.